# Can I use the captureAudio function of Capacitor's Media Capture class without using the phone's audio recording app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile, audio-recording, capacitor

I want to start recording audio on a mobile app while a button's pressed. I managed to implement audio recording using ionic's Media Capture class. However, it doesn't work as I intend it to. The way it's working right now is that I tap a button and the phone's native audio recording app gets started and allows me to record something. I would like to do the audio recording without having to switch screens, similar to how you record a voice note in WhatsApp. Been looking everywhere for an answer but haven't found anything. Anyone knows how would one go about doing this?

Comment: Capacitor doesn’t have a media capture API, so can you explain what are you doing?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Ionic native... Edited it.

Answer (score 1):

This post is old but for anybody coming across this, by using the ionic-native media plugin rather than the media capture plugin it is possible to connect the audio recording to a button

```
import { Media, MediaObject } from "@ionic-native/media/ngx";

constructor(private media: Media);

hStartRecordAudio(): {
    const lDate = new Date();

    this.audioName = `Recording_${lDate}.m4a`;

    this.audioFile = this.media.create(this.filePath.replace(/file:\/\//g, "") + this.audioName);

    this.hAudioRecordingStarted = true;
    this.audioFile.startRecord();
}

hEndRecordAudio() {
    this.audioFile.release();
    this.hAudioRecordingStarted = false;

    setTimeout(() => {
        let content = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(this.filePath + this.audioName)
    });
}
```